# Serialized data doesn't match deserialized data in tenserflow TFRecordDataset code

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I have a large dataset of numpy integers which I want to analyze with a GPU. The dataset is too large to fit into main memory on the GPU so I am trying to serialize them into a TFRecord and then use the API to stream the record for processing. The below code is example code: it wants to create some fake data, serialize it into the TFRecord object, then using a TF session read the data back into memory, parsing with the map() function. My original data is non-homogenous in terms of the dimensions of the numpy arrays, though each is a 3D array with 10 as the length of the first axis. I recreated the hetorogeneity using random numbers when I made the fake data. The idea is to store the size of each image as I serialize the data, and I can use that to restore each array to its original size. But when I deserialize there are two issues: first of all the data going in does not match the data coming out (serialized doesn't match deserialized). Secondly, the iterator to get all of the serialized data out is incorrect. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from skimage.io import ImageCollection 
import tensorflow as tf
import argparse

#A function for parsing TFRecords
def record_parser(record):
    keys_to_features = {
            'fil' : tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.string),
            'm'   : tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.int64),
            'n'   : tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.int64)} 

    parsed = tf.parse_single_example(record, keys_to_features)

    m    = tf.cast(parsed['m'],tf.int64)
    n    = tf.cast(parsed['n'],tf.int64)

    fil_shape = tf.stack([10,m,n])
    fil = tf.decode_raw(parsed['fil'],tf.float32)
    print("size: ", tf.size(fil))
    fil = tf.reshape(fil,fil_shape)
    return (fil,m,n)

#For writing and reading from the TFRecord
filename = "test.tfrecord"

if __name__ == "__main__":

    #Create the TFRecordWriter
    data_writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(filename)

    #Create some fake data
    files = []
    i_vals = np.random.randint(20,size=10)
    j_vals = np.random.randint(20,size=10)

    print(i_vals)
    print(j_vals)
    for x in range(5):
        files.append(np.random.rand(10,i_vals[x],j_vals[x]).astype(np.float32))

    i=0
    #Serialize the fake data and record it as a TFRecord using the TFRecordWriter
    for fil in files:
        i+=1
        f,m,n = fil.shape
        fil_raw = fil.tostring()
        print(fil.shape)
        example = tf.train.Example(
            features = tf.train.Features(
                feature = {
                    'fil' : tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[fil_raw])),
                    'm'   : tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[m])),
                    'n'   : tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[n]))
                }
            )
        )
        data_writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    data_writer.close()

    #Deserialize and report on the fake data
    sess = tf.Session()

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([filename])
    dataset = dataset.map(record_parser)

    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

    next_element = iterator.get_next()

    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    while True:
        try:
            sess.run(next_element)
            fil,m,n = (next_element[0],next_element[1],next_element[2])
            with sess.as_default():
                print("fil.shape: ",fil.eval().shape)
                print("M: ",m.eval())
                print("N: ",n.eval())
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
```

And here is the output:

```
MacBot$ python test.py
/Users/MacBot/anaconda/envs/tflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:34: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
[ 6  7  3 18  9 10  4  0  3 12]
[ 4  2 14  4 11  4  5  2  9 17]
(10, 6, 4)
(10, 7, 2)
(10, 3, 14)
(10, 18, 4)
(10, 9, 11)
2018-04-03 10:52:29.324429: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
size:  Tensor("Size:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
fil.shape:  (10, 7, 2)
M:  3
N:  4
```

Anybody understand what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
sess.run(iterator.initializer)
while True:
    try:
        sess.run(next_element)
        fil,m,n = (next_element[0],next_element[1],next_element[2])
        with sess.as_default():
            print("fil.shape: ",fil.eval().shape)
            print("M: ",m.eval())
            print("N: ",n.eval())
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        break
```

it should be

```
sess.run(iterator.initializer)
while True:
    try:
        fil,m,n = sess.run(next_element)
        print("fil.shape: ",fil.eval().shape)
        print("M: ",m.eval())
        print("N: ",n.eval())
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        break
```